# Grails upgrade to 3.2 broke springsecurity with config type requestmap

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails3, grails3.2.0, grails-spring-security

After upgrading Grails from 3.1.8 to 3.2.4 the application was stuck in a redirection loop, always tried to redirect to /login/auth. Typical behaviour for missing requestmap entries. I have tried to upgrade hibernate4 as well, as described in the upgrade notes of grails 3.2

Original dependencies from working application with Grails 3.1.8

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
```

According to upgrade notes

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.10.Final"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.3.10.Final"
```

but the application is still trapped in this redirection loop. I identified clearly the requestmaps as the root cause for the problem, because I deactivated this feature and switched to static rules. Are there any suggestion which dependencies to use for getting springsecurity plugin working with Grails 3.1.8?

Following springsecurity version is used:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to call `springSecurityService.clearCachedRequestMaps()`

See:

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#requestmap-cache

Comment: thanks, that's it, it was not clear for me to call the clearCachedRequestmaps() method also in Bootstrap.groovy as well, as you described here: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/issues/489